# Adding vacuum region in PACKMOL

Tags: molecular-dynamics, packmol

How do you specify a symmetric vacuum region (along z) above and below an inorganic substrate using PACKMOL? I tried to increase the box size in .pdb and use that in packmol. But it changes the box dimensions and places the substrate diagonally across?

The input file:

```
tolerance 2.0 
filetype pdb 
output interface.pdb
structure TiO2-110.pdb 
number 24 
inside box 
0.0 0.0 0.0 
11.152 7.604 17.0 
end structure 
structure styrene.pdb 
number 11 
inside box
0. 0. 5.0
5.0 5.0 10.0 
end structure
```

Comment: +1 and welcome to our new community! Thank you for contributing your question here and we hope to see much more of you in the future! By the way, how did you find us? We've had very few PACKMOL questions here before (I created the PACKMOL tag just now).

Comment: Please add your PACKMOL input and the initial molecule structure file with the question.

Comment: The input file for packmol:

Comment: The input file: tolerance 2.0
filetype pdb
output interface.pdb

structure TiO2-110.pdb
  number 24
  inside box 0.0 0.0 0.0 11.152 7.604 17.0
end structure

structure styrene.pdb
  number 11
  inside box 0. 0. 5.0. 5.0 5.0 10.0
end structure

Comment: I have a slab which I need to position in the center and above and below the vacuum.  Is this possible?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but does the .pdb format contain any information regarding the simulation box? To phrase the question better, does the file "interface.pdb" contain any information regarding box size?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify `outside box A B C D E F` for a particular species or structure to be placed outside a region. This statement goes inside the `structure` block the same way as the `inside box A B C D E F` statement, where A B C are minimum coordinates and D E F are maximum coordinates.

Then if you make all molecules of all kinds and structures be `outside` of a particular region, that will be your vacuum.

To ensure that the total dimensions are approximately what you request, use `add_box_sides X` at the end of the packmol input script after all the `structure` blocks. That will add explicit dimensions to the output file if that file is `xyz` and make the total dimensions be *approximately* (largest box dimension) + 2 * X. I am not sure why the correspondence between the resulting output and (box size) + 2 * X is not always exact, but it has always been close enough for my personal applications.